# Multiplicar linha

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal como posso multiplicar o valor total das linha sendo que eu quero multiplicar valor por valor de cada linha

```css
var bloco1 = $("table tr").find("td").eq(0).val();
var bloco2 = $("table tr").find("td").eq(1).val();
var bloco3 = $("table tr").find("td").eq(2).val();

var valor = eval(bloco1) * eval(bloco2) * eval(bloco3);

$("#result").html(valor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
              <tr>
                 <th>exe</th>
                 <th>coluna2</th>
                 <th>coluna3</th>
                 <th>coluna4</th>
                 <th>coluna5</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <th>linha1</th>
                 <td><a href="#">10</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">20</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">15</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">5</a></td>
              </tr>
                 <tr>
                 <th>linha2</th>
                 <td><a href="#">20</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">28</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">12</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">11</a></td>
              </tr>               
              <tr>
                 <th>linha3</th>
                 <td><a href="#">3</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">5</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">2</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">8</a></td>
              </tr>
    
         </table>
<p id="result">Resultado: </p>
```

Comment: Multiplicar o valor da coluna ? como seria isto?

Comment: Não entendi, você que o valor de linhas ou o valor contido nas linhas?
achei um pouco confuso a pergunta

Comment: user3010128  - eu quero pegar os valores contido nas linha e multiplicar linha por linha. exe: 10 * 20 = 200 - 200 * 3 =600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
$('tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    if (i == 0) return; // para não contar com a primeira linha de titulos
    var nome = $(this).find('th').text(); // vai buscar o nome
    var valor = $(this).find('td a').get().reduce(function(sum, el) {
        return sum * parseFloat(el.innerHTML); // multiplica todos os valores da linha
    }, 1);
    var p = $('<p/>', { // cria um elmento "p" com o resultado
        html: [nome, valor].join(': ')
    });
    $('#result').append(p);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dt6orytk/

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar usar um loop para percorrer todos os elementos e obter o valor de cada um e multiplicá-los.

```
var blocos = $("table tr").find("td");
var total = 1;

blocos.each(function (index, element) {
  total *= parseInt($(this).find('a').text());
});

console.log(total);
```

No exemplo, primeiro obtive todas as `tds` e adicionei em um único objeto, depois uso o `each` para percorrer cada um, então acesso o elemento utilizando o `this` e pego o valor que está na tag `a`, converto para inteiro e multiplico todos os valores.

Answer (score 1):

Vai precisar colocar um identificador em cada tr.

```
<table border="1">
              <tr id="0">
                 <th>exe</th>
                 <th>coluna2</th>
                 <th>coluna3</th>
                 <th>coluna4</th>
                 <th>coluna5</th>
              </tr>
              <tr id="1">
                 <th>linha1</th>
                 <td><a href="#">10</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">20</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">15</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">5</a></td>
              </tr>
                 <tr id ="2">
                 <th>linha2</th>
                 <td><a href="#">20</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">28</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">12</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">11</a></td>
              </tr>               
              <tr id="3">
                 <th>linha3</th>
                 <td><a href="#">3</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">5</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">2</a></td>
                 <td><a href="#">8</a></td>
              </tr>

         </table>
<p id="result">Resultado: </p>
```

Depois realizar um each para recuperar as informações de cada linha

```
var array1 = array();
var array2 = array();
var array3 = array();

$("#1 a").each(function (index, element) {
     //armazenar no array 1
     array1[index] = parseInt($(this).html()); 
});
...
$("#3 a").each(function (index, element) {
     //armazenar no array 3
     array3[index] = parseInt($(this).html()); 
});
```

Depois você pode utilizar os array para realizar qualquer tipo de cálculo.